# sharing files/folders over vpn?

Tags: windows-xp, vpn

Is there any way to share folders or files between two computers using windows xp over a vpn connection.

I have searched for it so much but cant find a solution, also have tried by enabling a folder option of "network sharing and security" but it also didn't work, so any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

\ipoftheremote host ... you need to disable firewall etc .. depending on the VPN software you may not be able to talk to other host on the network with different protocalls ..

- ping the remote host
- if you can ping it try to net use \IP or just goto start then type \IPOFTHEREMOTEHOST or \HOSTNAME
- if that does not work its most lilky firewall or some other stupid app blocking SMB share

  netsh advfirewall set AllProfiles state off

Comment: no i connected by completely turning off the firewall, so thre is no way firewall is blocking, or bu that did you mean offing firewall from GUI is different from offing it from CUI or netsh.